# Xcode pop up menu in build settings, how do I get there?

Tags: xcode

I'm following the tutorial for adding grabkit to my project here:

https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit/wiki/How-to-install-GrabKit

and it asks me to add some seetings to header search paths. However, I can't seem to get the screen that they have after clicking everything that I can. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you fail? There are a number of steps in this picture... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double clicking where it says `<Multiple values>`.

Comment: it doesn't say multiple values on my screen

Comment: that screenshot is from the tutorial, mine says - $(inherited) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include

Comment: How about double clicking in the column where `<Multiple values>` would appear?

Comment: I had to click on the third column's value.